# animatewithduration not working?

Tags: ios, animation, rotation

Hey all I'm trying to rotate an image based on data i'm getting. The image does rotate, but there is no animation.

Here's the code..

```
UIImage *arrowimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"];

NSInteger degrees = [_item.current_value integerValue] ;

NSLog(@"ANIMATION!!");

_imageView.image = arrowimage;
_curvalLabel.text = @"";

[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    _imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI / 180.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
}];
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout or autoresizing masks?

Comment: in your completion is _finished==YES_?

Comment: @bilobatum auto layout. nielsbot uhm finished is null if i print it? :x

Comment: Your code worked fine for me with an image view centered horizontally and vertically using constraints. Where do you have this code? Can you show the whole method where it's located?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform,degrees * M_PI / 180.0);
```

Comment: add [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
                     [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]; above  _imageView.transform...

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the animation because your constraints are probably not "transform friendly". Some types of constraints don't play well with auto layout.

Post information about your constraints, or better, do a search for auto layout and transform.